# Getting null value after sending through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the code where I am sending data using `Intent` object.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Code.this, Code1.class);
intent.putExtra("question", R.string.id7);
intent.putExtra("output",R.string.modname1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the code where I am getting `Intent` object result.

```
Intent intent  = getIntent();
String mess =  intent.getStringExtra("message");
String output = intent.getStringExtra("output");
```

I also tried `Bundle` instead of `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

**At first Use**

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.id7);
 getResources().getString(R.string.modname1);
```

**FYI**

```
 String mess =  intent.getStringExtra("message"); // message is null
```

Your **KEY** is absent .

***Step 1***

```
 intent.putExtra("question", getResources().getString(R.string.id7));
 intent.putExtra("output",getResources().getString(R.string.modname1));
```

***Step 2***

```
  String mess =  intent.getStringExtra("question");
  String output = intent.getStringExtra("output");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference:

```
intent.putExtra("question", getResources().getString(R.string.id7));
```

You are using `question` while sending.

But you are retrieving as `message` :

```
String mess =  intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

This is why your result `question` is null.

You must do while retrieving value:

```
String mess =  intent.getStringExtra("question");
```

Comment: #Satan, `R.string.id7` is not correct . We should use `getResources().getString(R.string.id7)`

Comment: Now it looks perfect.

Comment: It seems so :D .